# What is difference between moving location counter in a linker script and making empty space

Tags: linux-kernel, linker-scripts

I have a question about linker script "vmlinux.lds.S" in the Linux kernel, v4.6. Since its code is quite long, I post a link for it: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-wear-5.1.1_r0.6/arch/arm64/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F

As far as I know, moving location counter(.) in a linker script makes empty space. For instance, by saying ". += 1000" one gets 1000 bytes of empty space.
However, the linker script starts with:

```
    . = PAGE_OFFSET + TEXT_OFFSET;
```

Here, page offset is a (virtual) start address of the kernel space.(i.e. 0xFF...FF00...00)

Ofcourse, assigning this large value to location counter doesn't mean that we get such big empty space. Only VMA is assigned, and LMA is someting like 0x8000.

1. Why this code doesn't generate large empty space? Is there any exceptional rule about moving location counter?
2. What determines actual LMA of the kernel code(starting with _stext section)?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand it’s simple a hint to linker at which address you would like to load the code to.

Comment: @0andriy Right, using "AT" directive. In x86-64 vmlinux.lds it is used, but I found no hint in ARM64 version. Do you know where it is?